# iScroll sticks inside another iScroll

Tags: iscroll4, iscroll

My question is near similar to [Have carousel iScroll inside an existing vertical iScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157289/have-carousel-iscroll-inside-an-existing-vertical-iscroll), just one exception: I need the snap scroll mode for the vertical iScroll too. But when dragging any horizontal scroller from right to left firsttime, it sticks. Any solution to avoid this?

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5Fjg/ (edited code from http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/r9VL2/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a library, [Motus.js](https://bitbucket.org/rcafolla/motus.js) that might do what you're after.